# Python win32com functions for Linux

Tags: python, excel

I'm looking for win32com alternative which will work on Linux. As win33com won't work in Linux. Now, we are using win32com but we are planning to move to Linux. We are using below script for refresh Excel pivot table. We need python script for same which will work on Linux.
Kindly advise

'''

import win32com.client

```
# Start an instance of Excel
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb = xlapp.workbooks.open(<path_to_excel_workbook>)

# Optional, e.g. if you want to debug
# xlapp.Visible = True

# Refresh all data connections.
wb.RefreshAll()
wb.Save()
```

'''

Comment: The `win32` part of the name should be a good clue that this won't be possible.

Comment: Yes.. but we are looking for script to refresh Excel pivot table which will work on Linux. Any alternative.